# I am trying to count the number of attachments uploading via case object. But it is getting null. How to resolve this?

Tags: apex, trigger

This is an attachment class which i use to count the number of attachments

**Trigger**

```
trigger TriggerToCheckOfAttachment on ContentDocument (after insert) {

       AttachmentTask.TriggerTask(trigger.new);

    }
```

**Trigger Handler**

```
  public class AttachmentTask {

public static void TriggerTask(list<ContentDocument> getDocument) { 
     string docId;
    list<Id> parentTaskIdSet = new list<id>();
    set<Id> linkentityId = new set<id>();
    system.debug(getDocument);
    for(ContentDocument docObj :getDocument)
    {
        if(docObj.id!=null)
        {

            parentTaskIdSet.add(docObj.id);
             docId = docObj.Id;
        }

    }
   system.debug('docid'+docId);// here it is getting value
    list<ContentDocumentLink> selectEntity = [select id,linkedentityid   
                                              from ContentDocumentLink  
                                              where contentdocumentid =: docId];
    system.debug(selectEntity);
    for(ContentDocumentLink docObj: selectEntity)
    {
        if(docObj.LinkedEntityId!=null)
        {
            linkentityId.add(docObj.LinkedEntityId);
        }
    }
    system.debug('bodyid'+linkentityId);//Here it is null.
```

> But if i  try in query editor it shows two values. Here i need help
>   guys

```
    list<case> updateCase = new list<case>();
    list<case> getCases = [select id, AccountId, AssetId, BusinessHoursId, CaseNumber, Origin, OwnerId, Count__c ,(select id from attachments)
                           from Case
                           where id in : linkentityId ];
    for(case caseObj: getCases)
    {
        if(caseObj.Id!=null)
        {
            caseObj.Count__c = caseObj.attachments.size();
            updateCase.add(caseObj);
        }

    }
    update updateCase;

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The reason for your issue is that

- an afterInsert of `ContentDocument` will occur *before any ContentDocumentLink* records are even inserted! Hence none will exist.
- That is, the ContentDocument has to exist before a ContentDocumentLink can be saved as it is a junction record between ContentDocument and the object pointed at by LinkedEntityId

You'll need to rethink this, perhaps by having a trigger on `ContentDocumentLink` instead. I can't tell what your business problem is from the description but it seems as if you want a count of attachments on the Case object. This specific operation can be done by using the Declarative Lookup Rollup Summary package using just clicks (although there seems to be an [issue with counting deleted CDL](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries/issues/433)

Comment: I have changed the trigger on content version. But how will i  link it with case id to get the attachment count?. Or is this is wrong

Comment: I suggested using `ContentDocumentLink`, not `ContentVersion` as CDL points at the parent Case(s)

Answer (score 0):

You missed inner SOQL to get related attachments i.e `(select id from attachments)`, and you are checking `attachments.size()` inside for loops without child results(attachments). Below are the changes I did in your code

Changes in your code

```
list <case >updateCase = new list < case >();
list < case >getCases = [select id, AccountId, AssetId, BusinessHoursId, CaseNumber, Origin, OwnerId, Count__c ,(select id from attachments)from Case
        where id in : linkentityId
    ];
for (case caseObj:getCases) {
    if (caseObj.Id != null) {
        caseObj.Count__c = caseObj.attachments.size();
        updateCase.add(caseObj);
    }

}
update updateCase;
```

Comment: I used query editor to get the contentbodyid,id from content version but i am not getting it while running the console